# Low water pressure in the early morning hours

Tags: plumbing

Good morning. I am having a real problem that no on seems to know how to fix. In the early morning between 4 am and 7 am I have no water pressure. It is impossible to take a shower. The whole house has no water pressure. At first I thought it was the sprinklers outside that went on from 1-3 am that was the cause of this. The sprinkler system has been cut off and I still have no pressure. Please help. Also note, no one else on my block wakes up at 4 in the morning to shower and no one else on my block has experienced this problem. PLEASE help. This is ruining my mornings!!! Thank you !

Comment: Assuming you have city water service and not your own well.  Is this problem new?  Have you always lived there? Or is this the first summer?  Is your house geographically higher up (hill) than most?  You mention your irrigation system has been turned off, but do you neighbors have irrigation systems?  Our house is at the top of a hill, during high volume peak water usage hours in the morning there is no question our pressure drops, not as much as yours.

Comment: Have you tried contacting your utility?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the water softener hours for running and doing it back flush (if you have one).

If it is not a running softener, a water pressure gauge that attaches to your hose bib is a fairly cheap purchase.  If you obtain one hook it up to your hose bib and record the pressure low values and what you consider normal values.

Then obtain permission from one of your nearest neighbors to attach it to their hose bib.  And record the pressure at the same time you had recorded your values.  This will isolate if it is just your home or the whole neighborhood.  If it is the whole neighborhood take the readings to your water service provider and request them to investigate.

Comment: Thank you Niall C. I had to have missed the save on last changes fixing the spell checks and proof reads.  I will have to work harder at that.  No excuse, but cancer related infusions make some days not work as I like.